# form table creation, template display and view processing

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

[This is a refactor of a previous question, and I hope this question is more clear.]

I have a an activity model that holds a number and is dependent on a person and a category.

```
class Activity( models.Model ):
   person = models.ForeignKey( Person )  # approx 80 people
   category = models.ForeignKey( Category ) # approx 6 categories
   value = models.FloatField( )
```

The users would like to have a table with category across the top and person down the side and then a value field in each cell if the table.

Currently my form is:

```
class MonthlyActivityForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs ):
        affiliations = kwargs.pop('affiliations')
        point_categories = kwargs.pop('point_categories')

        super(MonthlyActivityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for pc in point_categories:
            for a in affiliations:
                self.fields['pc-%d-pe-%d' % (pc.id, a.person.id)] = forms.FloatField()
```

I can't see how to do a table of form fields (nicely) in regular Django. I think it comes down to the form building which will affect the efficiency of the template and view processing.

First pass thought is to:

1) create a FloatField for each person,category create a template to create a table as described above (this part seems harder than it should be)

2) in the view, on a valid form run through each FloatField in the returned form and save any changes

So, I suppose there are two questions:

1) is there a more efficient method to create a table of FloatFields other than trying to figure out looping in the template to create a table with FloatFields in the td's?

2) how can I store the person.id and category.id in the FloatField such that when I go back to the view with a valid form then I can create/update the proper Activity entry? (or can I just grab it from the form key for each FloatField?)

I am reasonably new to Django, but it seems like it should be slightly easier.  I have to be missing something here.

Comment: Have you looked at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets ?

Comment: I had only very briefly... see below as I am not sure how that would be setup in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You could make this much simpler by using [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets). In this case I would probably have one form per user, containing all the category fields created dynamically, but the formset would take care of instantiating one of these forms per user.

Comment: `PersonActivityFormSet = modelformset_factory(Activity)`? And then repeat that per Person?  I don't want you to write all the code but could you give a brief example of this for my case?  [It does seem like what I am looking for]

Comment: Oh, I think I am understanding more.  I would have to create my own formset (with N FloatFields) rather than rely on the factor as I don't actually have a model for the *set* of categories.  (correct?)

Comment: A formset appears to be related to a model. I need to have a "formset" with N fields per person but each field is instance of Category, but the data needs to be stored back in Activity (related to the category and the person for the line).